# If $o(\mathrm{a})$ be finite, $\langle a\rangle\simeq \Bbb {Z}/m\Bbb{Z}$ for some positive integer $m$ using Isomorphism theorem.

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

Let $G$ be a group. A mapping $\phi: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow G$ is defined by
$\phi(n)=a^{n},$ where $a \in G$ and $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ show that
$\phi$ is a homomorphism. Moreover, if   $o(a)$ be finite, $\langle a\rangle\simeq \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{m\mathbb{Z}}$ for some positive integer $m$ using Isomorphism theorem.

**My attempt:**

> *First part :* For $m,n\in \mathbb{Z}, \phi({m+n})=a^{m+n}=a^ma^n=\phi(m)\phi(n)\implies \phi$ is homomorphism.

How can I show the $2^{\text{nd}}$ part?

Comment: Think about the kernel of $\phi$.

Comment: @BSC As $\mathbb{Z}$ is generated by $1$ the image of $\varphi$ must be generated by $\varphi(1)=a$, in other words equal to $\langle a \rangle$. By virtue of the fundamental isomorphism theorem, you have the isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}/\mathrm{Ker}\varphi \approx \langle a \rangle$ and taking into account that any subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ is of the form $m\mathbb{Z}$ we gather $\langle a \rangle \approx \mathbb{Z}_m$ for a certain $m \in \mathbb{N}$. In case $a$ is of finite order, $m\mathbb{Z}$ must be of finite index in $\mathbb{Z}$ which means that $m \neq 0$ *(to be cont.)*

Comment: @BSC *(cont.)* in which case $|\langle a \rangle|=\left|\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}\right|=(\mathbb{Z}\colon m\mathbb{Z})=m$.

Comment: I'm fairly sure this is a duplicate.

Comment: For the first part, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2895616/104041).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Let $G,H$ be groups and $\phi:G\rightarrow H$ be homomorphism. Then the First Isomorphism Theorem states that $$G/\ker \phi \cong \phi(G)$$

Let $m=o(a)$.
So first you had shown that $\phi$ is a homomorphism.
Next you want to show that $\phi(\Bbb{Z})=\langle a\rangle$.
Note that $\phi(\Bbb{Z})=\{a^z:z\in \Bbb{Z}\}=\langle a\rangle$ by the definition of subgroup generated by a single element.

Lastly you have to show that $\ker \phi =m\Bbb{Z}$.
Notice that $\ker \phi=\{z\in \Bbb{Z}:a^z=1\}$.
Recall a property that $a^z=1$ if and only if $m$ divides $z$.
Hence we get $\ker\phi=m\Bbb{Z}$ and the result follows.

Comment: I guess you meant $G/ker \phi\cong\phi(G)$, not $G/ker \phi\cong\phi(H)$.

Comment: @user750041 Corrected. Thanks.